# How can I check which hash function is being used to create block hash in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hash, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, cryptographic-hash-function

I have to change the default hash function of hyperledger fabric.
And to check if my hash function is being used, I need to check which hash function is being used to create a new block in hyperledger fabric.

Comment: why do you want to change the hashing algorithm for blocks?

Comment: It is for my university project.

Comment: updated my answer below with the location where the block hash also is set:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-2.1/common/channelconfig/util.go#L82

Comment: Can I know it when a network is running or a transaction is being performed?

Answer (score 0):

There is a config value for each channel name "HashingAlgorithm" but it cannot currently be modified.  It uses *SHA256*.  It is set here:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-2.1/common/channelconfig/util.go#L82

It is possible to change the hashing algorithm used by clients when signing transactions and used by peers when verifying this transactions.  This is done via the bccsp config.  If you want to create a custom hash algorithm and are using Fabric 2.0 or later, then you'll need to modify the core peer code and add your own bccsp provider.